# How to get my site using UTF-8 (PHP site)

Tags: utf-8

First time poster and hoping to solve a very frustrating issue.

In Google chrome, my PHP site displays random characters such as Â. However, when I switch the encoding to UTF-8 all the random characters clear up.

I've been reading elsewhere that that I need to tell me site to use UTF-8 by default. My host say this is already enabled on their side.

What code do I add and where to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Put:

```
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
```

In the `<head>` of the document, and it should force the page to render utf-8 characters properly.

Further description: In your HTML page, you would have the page layed out as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <!--<link> tags for any CSS-->
        <!--<script> tags for any JS-->
        <!--Anything else in the head-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Page contents-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No - this would go in the `<head>` tag of the HTML page. I've edited an example into the post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Death but my pages are created by users starting projects. I wouldn't be able to go back into each page and add that code. Isn't there a central file that is supposed to contain this info? I've read about including the code @charset "UTF-8"; in style.css but that didn't work...

Comment: If you have a constant `style.css` file accross all pages, then surely that must be defined somewhere on each page? If so, can't you just add the `<meta>` tag along with it? If not, then http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset.en#answer has some information on using `.htaccess` files to manage default charsets.